# Very basic model theory question

Tags: model-theory

Could someone tell me if my proof atempt goes in the right direction:

Claim: Let $T$ be a $\tau$-theory. We say that $T´$ is an axiomatization of $T$ if for every model $M$ we have $M \models T$ iff $M \models T´$. Show that $T \models \varphi$ iff $T´ \models \varphi$ for any $\tau$- formula.

Proof. $(\Rightarrow)$ Let  $\varphi$ be an atomic formula, $T$ a $\tau$-teoria such that  $T \models \varphi$ e $T'$ an axiomatization of $T$. Trivially $T' \models T'$, then by definition of axiomatization  $T' \models T$. Now by transitivity of the consequence relation $T' \models  \varphi$. For the other direction I would proceed analogously.

I have the feelin that the proof is wrong since neither $T$ nor $T´$ are models but only set of sentences. Am I right ? I would appreciate any type of help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Hint*

You have to play with the two usages of $\vDash$...

Example : assume $T \vDash \varphi$. This means that, for every $\mathscr M$ we have : $\text {if } \mathscr M \vDash T, \text { then } \mathscr M \vDash \varphi$.

But the premise of the theorem is : for every model $\mathscr M :  \mathscr M \vDash T \text { iff } \mathscr M \vDash T'$.

Thus : if $\mathscr M \vDash T'$, then $\mathscr M \vDash \varphi$, which amounts to :

> $T' \vDash \varphi$.

Comment: Thanks @Mauro!! I was thinkin about this, but I was not sure if I could infer the last step !